# Kivy: Having trouble getting ListView to update when sorting ListAdapter data

Tags: python, listview, sorting, listadapter, kivy

I'm trying to sort a list of dictionaries in a listview.  I'm going about it by changing the ListAdapter.data.

In the kv file a spinner button above the listview selects the sort value and on_release makes a call to root.beer_sort which changes the ListAdapter (named beer_la) data.  Printing out the beer_la.data to the console, it looks like it changes, but the App's display order doesn't update.

```
class CellarDoor(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.beer_archive = []
        self.wine_archive = []
        with open(join(FILE_ROOT, 'beer_archive.csv'), 'rb', 1) as beer_csv:
            self.beer_archive = list(csv.DictReader(beer_csv))

        self.beer_la = ListAdapter(data=self.beer_archive, 
                          args_converter=self.beer_formatter,
                          cls=CompositeListItem,         
                          selection_mode='single',
                          allow_empty_selection=True)
        super(CellarDoor, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def beer_formatter(self, row_index, beer_data):
        return {'text': beer_data['Beer'],
                'size_hint_y': None,
                'height': 50,
                'cls_dicts': [{'cls': ListItemImage,
                               'kwargs': {'size_hint_x': .2,
                                          'size': self.parent.size,
                                          'cellar': 'Beer',
                                          'style': beer_data['Style']}},
                              {'cls': ListItemLabel,
                               'kwargs': {'text': beer_data['Beer']}},
                              {'cls': ListItemButton,
                               'kwargs': {'text': str(beer_data['Stock'])}}]}

    def beer_sort(self, sort, reverse):
        self.beer_la.data = sorted(self.beer_archive,
                                   key=lambda k: k[sort],
                                   reverse=reverse)
        print "new sort = %s" % sort
        print self.beer_la.data
```

The relevant portion of the kv file

```
<CellarDoor>
    ...
    Spinner:
        id: beer_sort_spinner
        text: 'Brewery'
        values: ['Brewery', 'Beer', 'Year', 'Style', 'Stock', 'Rating', 'Price']
        on_release: root.beer_sort(self.text, (True if future_search_button.state=='down' else False))
    ToggleButton:
        id: future_search_button
        text: 'Reverse'
    Button:
        text: 'Add Beer'
    ListView:
        adapter: root.beer_la
```

Comment: This a known issue with the current version and being worked on. As a workaround for now you can do the following:

    <ListView>:
        on_adapter: self.adapter.bind_triggers_to_view(self._trigger_reset_populate)
 or pass the adapter as the argument to the ListView while instanciating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I can help a little bit with your problem. I found out that if I add the list view after calling the constructor of the `CellarDoor` (instead of using Kivy Language) then the `sort` method start working. My example is a simplified version of yours but the behaviour that you describe was still present.

If you uncomment:

```
#    ListView:
#        adapter: root.beer_la
```

and comment:

```
        self.add_widget(ListView(adapter=self.beer_la))
```

then, the sorting stop working just as you describe.

Curiously, if I have a big list (let's say 100), the `ListView` is updated after performing and action on it (scrolling or selecting) and item. Somehow this means that the property of the adapter is not bound to update the screen. This could be an issue that might deserve to be reported to the developers in [Github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/). I cannot explain you better but I hope at least it solves your problem. You might also want to try [create and add the adapter directly in Kivy Language](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html#using-an-adapter).

```
from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_string("""
<CellarDoor>:
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Reverse'
        on_state: root.beer_sort((True if self.state=='down' else False))
#    ListView:
#        adapter: root.beer_la
""")

class CellarDoor(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.beer_archive = ["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(10)]
        self.beer_la = ListAdapter(data=self.beer_archive, 
                          cls=ListItemButton,
                          selection_mode='single',
                          allow_empty_selection=True)

        super(CellarDoor, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(ListView(adapter=self.beer_la))


    def beer_sort(self, reverse):
        self.beer_la.data = sorted(self.beer_archive,
                                   reverse=reverse)
        print self.beer_la.data

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CellarDoor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much toto_tico.  This seems to be working out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone with the same problem...

I ran into similar issues when adding new elements to a ListView won't update the list.
Setting the data property again when updating (as proposed above) actually didn't worked out for me (Kivy 1.8.0).

Somewhere in the Kivy Google Groups, a solution using the ListViews .populate() method was shown.

```
def update_data(self):
  self.list_adapter.data = mydata
  self.list_view.populate()
```

One of the problems with this method is, that the .populate() attribute doesn't seem to exist directly after creation of the ListView. So you have to check if the attribute exists prior to calling it:

```
def update_data(self):
  self.list_adapter.data = mydata
  if(hasattr(self.list_view, 'populate')):
    self.list_view.populate()
```

This actually worked out, but unfortunately new items on the bottom of the list are visible, but you are unable to scroll down to these items.

After digging through the source of the ListView, I came across the ._reset_spopulate() method, which seems to do exactly what I want:

```
def update_data(self):
  self.list_adapter.data = mydata
  if(hasattr(self.list_view, '_reset_spopulate')):
    self.list_view._reset_spopulate()
```

New items on the bottom are added correctly and scrolling works as well.
Don't ask me why exactly this works, and don't expect this to work in future versions of Kivy.

Answer (score 0):

In the "[Creating apps in Kivy](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/creating-apps-in/9781491947333/)" book from O'Reilly it suggests the `_trigger_reset_populate()` function:

```
    def update_data(self):
        self.list_adapter.data = mydata
        self.list_view._trigger_reset_populate()
```